# Count tweets between dates (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database

I have an assignment to create a twitter like database. And in this assignment i have to filter out the trending topics. My idea was to count the tweets with a specific tag between the date the tweet was made and 7 days later, and order them by the count.

I have the following 2 tables i am using for this query :

```
Table Tweet : id , message, users_id, date

Table Tweet_tags : id, tag, tweet_id
```

Since mysql isn't my strong point at all im having trouble getting any results from the query.
The query i tried is :

```
Select
      Count(twitter.tweet_tags.id) As NumberofTweets,
      twitter.tweet_tags.tag
From twitter.tweet 
Inner Join twitter.tweet_tags On twitter.tweet_tags.tweet_id = twitter.tweet.id 
WHERE twitter.tweet_tags.tag between twitter.tweet.date and ADDDATE(twitter.tweet.date, INTERVAL 7 day) 
ORDER BY NumberofTweets
```

The query works, but gives no results. I just can't get it to work. Could you guys please help me out on this, or if you have a better way to get the trending topics please let me know!

Thanks alot!

Comment: On an tangential not, it's not a good idea to specify the database name in your queries. Simple select 'twitter' as the default database, and omit the database name from the actual query.  It may not really matter here, but think of a real-world application where the database name was hardcoded.  What if you wanted to have a separate production db and test db, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to your query, with table aliases to make it easier to read, with BETWEEN replaced by two inequality predicates, and the ADDDATE function replaced with equivalent operation...

```
SELECT COUNT(s.id) As NumberofTweets
     , s.tag
  FROM twitter.tweet t 
  JOIN twitter.tweet_tags s 
    ON s.tweet_id = t.id
 WHERE s.tag >= t.date 
   AND s.tag <= t.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
 ORDER
    BY NumberofTweets
```

Two things pop out at me here...

First, there is no `GROUP BY`. To get a count by "tag", you want at `GROUP BY tag`.

Second, you are comparing "tag" to "date".  I don't know your tables, but that just doesn't look right. (I expect "date" is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, and "tag" is a character string (maybe what my daughter calls a "hash tag". Or is that tumblr she's talking about?)

---

If I understand your requirement:

For each tweet, and for each tag associated with that tweet, you want to get a count of the number of other tweets, that have a matching tag, that are made within 7 days after the datetime of the tweet.

One way to get this result would be to use a correlated subquery. (This is probably the easiest approach to understand, but is probably not the best approach from a performance standpoint).

```
SELECT t.id
     , s.tag
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM twitter.tweet_tags r
           JOIN twitter.tweet q
             ON q.id = r.tweet_id
          WHERE r.tag = s.tag
            AND q.date >= t.date
            AND q.date <= t.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
       ) AS cnt
  FROM twitter.tweet t 
  JOIN twitter.tweet_tags s 
    ON s.tweet_id = t.id
 ORDER
    BY cnt DESC
```

Another approach would be to use a join operation:

```
SELECT t.id
     , s.tag
     , COUNT(q.id) AS cnt
  FROM twitter.tweet t 
  JOIN twitter.tweet_tags s 
    ON s.tweet_id = t.id
  LEFT
  JOIN twitter.tweet_tags r
    ON r.tag = s.tag
  LEFT
  JOIN twitter.tweet q
    ON q.id = r.tweet_id
       AND q.date >= t.date
       AND q.date <= t.date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
 GROUP
    BY t.id
     , s.tag
 ORDER
    BY cnt DESC
```

The counts from both of these queries assume that `tweet_tags (tweet_id, tag)` is unique. If there are any "duplicates", then including the DISTINCT keyword, i.e. `COUNT(DISTINCT q.id)` (in place of `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(q.id)` respectively) would get you the count of "related" tweets.

NOTE: the counts returned will include the original tweet itself.

NOTE: removing the `LEFT` keywords from the query above should return an equivalent result, since the tweet/tag (from t/s) is guaranteed to match itself (from r/q), as long as the tag is not null and the tweet `date` is not null.

Those queries are going to have problematic performance on large sets.  Appropriate covering indexes are going to be needed for acceptable performance:

```
...  ON twitter.tweet_tags (tag, tweet_id)

...  ON twitter.tweet (date)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast response! However i get exactly the same results as with my query :(

Comment: @user1362916: that's because (as I stated) the first query in my response is EQUIVALENT to your query. (Your query is too hard to read.) It's the easier-to-read reformatted query that makes it easier to spot the problem. The later queries in my answer should return the result set you specified.

Comment: Thanks! Working Like a Charm!

Comment: PERFORMANCE NOTE: both of those queries are likely going to have performance issues on large sets. Appropriate covering indexes are going to be necessary for optimum performance.

Comment: Oh im sorry i just tried it again, it returns this : id: 1, tag : testtag , cnt : 5   , However i only have testtag 2 times in my database, and two other tags. So it should be Testtag 3, AnotherTag 1, Anothertagagain 1 , any idea what i have to change in order to get those results?

Comment: Your first example works! Only theres a duplicate entry in it, but im sure ill find a way to get this out! Thanks for your help and time

Comment: The last query was missing a `GROUP BY t.id, s.tag`; I've modified it, it should be returning an equivalent result to the correlated subquery now. That correlated subquery should not returning any duplicate 't.id, s.tag' tuples, unless there's a duplicate in the database. (The count is including the origin tweet in that count.)